# How can I get audio output from Google Glass to a 3.5mm headphone jack?

Tags: google-glass

Glass recently released headphones and a [mono ear bud](https://plus.google.com/111626127367496192147/posts/8PvftzvHT3e). This implies that it is capable of producing an audio signal from the Micro USB port.

Is it possible to create an adapter for Glass to connect to a standard audio connector, such as a 3.5mm headphone cable?

Comment: I typed `micro usb to 3.5mm` into Google and found this: http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Micro-USB-Jack-to-3-5mm-Headphone-Earphone-Adapter-Socket-Audio-Cable-Black-/160818117801

Comment: It needs to be supported by Glass, it's not clear if this would work since it needs some level of driver support.  Thanks though I'll look into it.

Comment: this seems like a neat hack (also on XDA), but it also seems like a cable you'll receive in the upcoming consumer Glass replacement - https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bkYDAu3OM5I/UnAxaJ_3NEI/AAAAAAAAPGU/vFY8ginsvx4/w1068-h712-no/earbud1.jpg

Comment: The _explorer_ Glass replacement only comes with a mono earbud and a fixed cable. The cable is very short and thin.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Why was this question closed? This was very helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware.

Comment: lilbyrdie: That's not the consumer replacement but V2. It's also not a cable but a mono-earbud. The answer below is from one of the actual Glass Engineers (Jenny Murphy) and provides the details needed to develop your own true, 3.5mm adapter cable. I've already seen one built and tested successfully. I'm going to build one as soon as Amazon gets me the parts and I'll provide a video walk-through of the build and test. Follow "Michael-Rainabba Richardson" on G+ if you're interested in that or other Glass info (I'm a Glass Explorer and developer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're handy with a soldering iron, it's pretty easy to make an adapter. Solder a 500k ohm resistor between pins 4 and 5 (ID and GND).

You'll need the following parts:

- A microUSB headset adapter with all 5 pins, [like this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CMDGSX6).
- A 500k ohm resistor
- Knowledge about the pinout of the Micro-B usb connector. [Wikipedia describes it pretty well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb#Plugs_physical_appearance).

Once you have them, follow these instructions:

1. Open up the headset adapter and take a look around. If you ordered the one linked above, you'll find pins 4 and 5 connected by a solder bridge, but if you have a different one you may find a something else, like a resistor.
2. Desolder pin 4 if you need to.
3. Solder the 500k ohm resistor between pins 5 (GND) and 4 (ID).

Comment: Awesome! Having said so, the microUSB adapter you mention has the 'L' usb pointing front. Would the same work with this one? http://www.amazon.com/Headphones-Earphones-Earpieces-Converter-Micro-USB/dp/B006G1FX9U/ref=pd_sim_sbs_cps_5

Comment: Maybe?  As long as it has all 5 conductors, you should be fine :)  If it works, please report back.

Comment: Bought the one @JennyMurphy linked to, works great. Shell pops off clean for easy access. I had to cut an alternate exit hole straight out the bottom to fit a coaxial 470k resistor, so the fact that the original cable points "forward" isn't an issue.

Comment: @tdevaux Have you tried this adapter?