# Is there a document on using the micro usb port on Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass

I just see the post that make your own Google Glass earphone. on [How can I get audio output from Google Glass to a 3.5mm headphone jack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738163/how-can-i-get-audio-output-from-google-glass-to-a-3-5mm-headphone-jack)

I'm curious that is there a document for Google Glass or Android in general document that defines that kind of function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's undocumented, but its pinout has been experimentally determined. When a 500kΩ resistor is placed between pin 4 (Sense) and pin 5 (GND) of a micro-USB plug, the system treats it as an audio device. The pinout is:

- Pin 1: +5V. This charges the battery. Glass can be charged while audio is active.
- Pin 2: Right audio out
- Pin 3: Left audio out
- Pin 4: Sense. Connect to Pin 5 with a 500kΩ resistor.
- Pin 5: GND

Comment: I'm using V1.0 Glass and I haven't tried the earbud on my Glass. But I haven't found any USB switch in teardown photos nor any related code in kernel source released in April. May be the 2.0 one is different?

Comment: I don't recall where, but I've heard some users state that the USB earbuds for 2.0 work for the first version.

Comment: For my own reference. In tear down photo in catwig.com, there is a BGA12 chip with mark AAU below Audio codec TWL6041. MAX14532E matches the mark and location of capacitor and resistor matches the pinout.

Answer (score 2):

Try to answer my own question with some research.

From the tear down images and [kernel source code](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap/+/00e718723a208966185f5618426cca8174ef48ae). I found something.

Google Glass uses a MAX14532E chip to switch 3 functions: USB, TTY, Audio, or nothing.

However the ID resistor checking routine only check 500K(Stereo) or 1M(Mono). If resistor of those two values are detected the micro usb will switch to Audio automatically. I still need to do more test to see if I can switch it manually.