# Capturing Audio from a Google Glass app

Tags: android, audio, google-glass, demo

I'd like to capture the audio from a Glass app I'm creating for demonstration purposes (it makes quite a bit of use of the text-to-speech engine). I have video capture working (using [this tutorial](http://googleglassfans.com/archives/3814/record-google-glass-screen-using-adb/)), but the output videos are silent.

One option I've considered is using a USB speaker that I could plug in (instead of the Glass earpiece); if one exists that is loud enough to be recorded directly, I could solve this problem in two passes by recording all the video, then re-running the test to record the audio separately, then mixing the two media streams together.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19738163/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make a Glass 3.5mm Audio adapter out of a resistor, some solder, and a micro USB adaptor.

I teach a lot of Glass classes, and used this trick to get high quality audio out of Glass that can connect by 3.5mm audio cable to presentation systems, you could easily record this source.

Follow these directions, and props to Jenny: http://little418.com/2014/06/make-a-3-5mm-audio-adapter-for-google-glass.html

I can verify these instructions work.

Here is a picture of my set up.  The Micro USB goes into Glass, and the female 3.5mm takes a 3.5mm male cable with 3.5mm male on the other side and can go directly into anything that takes a standard headphone wire.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, audio cannot be recorded with *screenrecord* at this time. This is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) under "Recording a device screen."

As a workaround, you can record another audio track using your laptop's mic and simply combine the audio and video into a single track using any video editor. This is the quickest way to get audio.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200437/record-tablets-screen-and-audio) is an interesting solution where it is mentioned that you can connect your phone's headphone output to the mic input on your computer. I have not tried this on Glass but you can try this with a compatible Micro USB to 3.5mm headset adapter.

Comment: Recording another audio track would be workable, but the challenge is exactly as you've observed: the audio output from Glass is not a standard headset form-factor, it's a micro USB.

I'll look into converting from the micro USB form factor to an audio in adapter and update this question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Note: According to the review for this product [[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004T6N67K/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004T6N67K), it should work as a 3.5mm output adaptor for the Google Glass USB port.